# How I can build 'How to use this app' tutorial inside my iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift

I built a new iOS app,
After I ended it they asked me to make a self inside app tutorial explaining How to use this app !!

They mean something like the tutorials you view them on some famous apps,

Like: **To add new item: press here**, *and they put an arrow signing to the add button*.

So I'm wondering if there is any solution or idea I can start with it to make this tutorial .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how they do it but i think ist just a Video or gif or something like this!

Comment: you can present a view controller or view with black background with animating arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want.

You could show a video as @wasted suggests.

Another way of solving this is to use a `UIPageViewController` which embeds other simple `UIViewControllers` containing images and text explaining what you app does. An example of how to do that is shown [here] (http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/)

You can also find several frameworks made for this purpose, here are some of them:

- https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios
- https://github.com/ephread/Instructions
- https://github.com/ariok/BWWalkthrough
- https://github.com/ruipfcosta/SwiftyWalkthrough

Hope that gives you something to work with.

Comment: Yes it's, from the first glance it is what I want, I hope it doesn't require a lot of modifications in my code. I will check soon.

Comment: If you "just" add a `UIPageViewController` and some simple views explaining what your app does, it should't be too bad and shouldn't alter your existing code (I haven't seen your code base of course so I'm guessing now). Good luck :)